# how can i call java.util.queue poll() method and not remove elements in my queue

Tags: java, queue

How do i call java.util.queue poll() to display updated data on jsf page in (LIFO) as they come from database without losing the data on my queue? 
i've implemented  LIFO like this:

```
Deque<String> url = new ArrayDeque<>();   
Queue<String> urlst = Collections.asLifoQueue(url);
```

Comment: Javadocs are your friend: [peek()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#peek--)

Comment: Or read the javadoc of [`Queue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) itself, which has a very nice "**Summary of Queue methods**". Down-voting for lack of research.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the `peek()` method which does not remove the returned element from your queue.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html

Comment: Peek() only return element at the head of the queue. I need a peek () method that can work like poll(). Return next item in the queue when called

Comment: What is the difference between "next item" and "head of the queue"?

Comment: @Victor Learn to read the javadoc. *"I need a peek () method that can work like poll()."*. That's exactly what it does. `peek()`: *Retrieves, but does not remove, the head of this queue*, `poll()`: *Retrieves and removes the head of this queue*. I don't think you can find anything that "work like" any closer than that. Do you?